# Dynamic Default value while defining column definition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, query-optimization, database-performance

I have a scenario in which I need a table definition wherein for unique value column I need a value starting from 1 with concatenation of 'TBL00'  + unique value. unique value should be such that if PrjId is changed then unique value should start from 1.

```sql
 create table TableA
    (
    PrjID bigint,
    RvId bigint,
    Uniquevalue varchar(1000) 
    default 'TBL00'+ (for every project, rvid i need a unique value but if projectid is changed then values should start from 1)
    )
```

I want to get this unique value at the time of insert, I don't want to update this value after records are inserted. The reason is there are millions of users that are acccesing this table at a time and an exclusive lock will be applied if I use an update statement.

[image]

Comment: Why not use an `IDENTITY` column, and then you can use a computed column to concatenate the values (which can also have a `UNIQUE INDEX/CONSTRAINT` against it.

Comment: @Larnu, I can't use Identity as after every different project I want my values to again start from 1, not from the last value.

Comment: Also, SQL Server 2008 has been *completely* unsupported for over **3 years**; it is *long* past time you finalised and implemented your upgrade path.

Comment: Then you should look at a `SEQUENCE`, and instead ensure that you control which one is used in your (presumably) calling procedure.

Comment: Some sample data would make things more clear

Comment: just added an example

Answer (score 1):

You don't want a default here.

You need a computed column instead

```sql
ALTER TABLE TableA
  ADD Uniquevalue AS 'TBL' + RIGHT('00' + CAST(RvId AS varchar(20)), 3);
```

---

Alternatively you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` when querying the data

```sql
SELECT *,
  'TBL' + RIGHT('00' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.PrjId, t.RvId ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS varchar(20)), 3) AS Uniquevalue 
FROM YourTable t;
```

Comment: What about partitioning by Project_id? this computed column doesn't cover this.